# When someone takes somebody's place, what does he say?

Tags: expressions

When someone took somebody's else place and the guilty person realizes what she has done, what does she say? Is something like "oh, sorry, I didn't know you were sitting here" okay? Or "You sat here?"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to say that you were unaware that you had taken someone's seat:

> Sorry, I didn't realize you were sitting here.
>
> Sorry, I didn't know someone was already sitting here.
>
> Sorry, I didn't know this seat was taken.